# Python Regex groups causing index errors

Tags: python, string, format

So, my interpereter is complaining about `IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple` when calling re.group(#) or re.groups() under specific circumstances. It is meant to return a phone number, such as +1 (555) 555-5555

Here is the regex used, as it is declared elsewhere:

```
self.phoneRegex = re.compile(r'(\+\d) (\(\d\d\d\)) (\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)')
```

Here is the code causing the issues:

```
for cell in self.cells:
    if '+1' in cell.text:
        print(self.pmo.groups()) #Works fine
        print("{} {} {}-{}".format(self.pmo.groups())) #Errors out.
        print("{} {} {}-{}".format(self.pmo.group(1), self.pmo.group(2),self.pmo.group(3), self.pmo.group(4))) #Also errors out.
        if isinstance(self.cursor(row=self.data['lst_row'], column=self.telCol).value, type(None)):
            self.cursor(row=self.data['lst_row'], column=self.telCol).value = "{} {};".format("{} {} {}-{}".format(self.pmo.group(2), self.pmo.group(2),self.pmo.group(3), self.pmo.group(4)))
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents\Programs\Python\E45 Contact Info Puller\main.py", line 289, in run
    print("{} {} {}-{}".format(self.pmo.groups()))
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Comment: Usually an error like that means the group `self.pmo.group(#)` just doesn't exist (it didn't match).  What you should do though is make a MVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  that way we can just coyp/paste your code and see.  And I bet in doing so, you'll find the bug! :)

Comment: @sniperd See the `print(self.pmo.groups())` call? That shows that the phone number exists, and shows that the indices are indeed valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this `string.format` line:

```
print("{} {} {}-{}".format(self.pmo.groups()))
```

`re` match groups are tuples, so here, you have 4 format substitutions, but you're trying to pass a single tuple (that contains 4 matches per your regex) instead of 4 separate argument for formatting.

You need to unpack (or splat) the tuple for the string formatting - notice the `*` added before `self.pmo.groups()`.

```
print("{} {} {}-{}".format(*self.pmo.groups()))
```

Comment: This error is also reproducible when manually unpacking these groups. (self.pmo.group(#))

Comment: @user24683 in those cases, what does `print(self.pmo.groups())` output?

Comment: It shows that there are 4 items in the tuple. ('+1' '(555)' '555' '5555')

Comment: @user24683 - you'll have to condense your code down because if I use a simple example with your regex and a string it matches, I can manually substitute with matches or use the `*` to restructure and my code works.

Comment: I did condense it down to what I could. I tried it the way you mentioned and that worked. Marked as answered. Not sure why it won't work the other ways.